# How to add custom fields in contact page in shopify?

Tags: shopify

I want to add a "Subject" field in the contact form. This is the form code for it:

```
{%- form 'contact', id: 'ContactForm' -%}

<div class="contact__fields">
  <div class="field">
    <input class="field__input" autocomplete="name" type="text" id="ContactForm-name" name="contact[{{ 'templates.contact.form.name' | t }}]" value="{% if form.name %}{{ form.name }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.name }}{% endif %}" placeholder="{{ 'templates.contact.form.name' | t }}">
    <label class="field__label" for="ContactForm-name">{{ 'templates.contact.form.name' | t }}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field field--with-error">
    <input
      autocomplete="email"
      type="email"
      id="ContactForm-email"
      class="field__input"
      name="contact[email]"
      spellcheck="false"
      autocapitalize="off"
      value="{% if form.email %}{{ form.email }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.email }}{% endif %}"
      aria-required="true"
      {% if form.errors contains 'email' %}
        aria-invalid="true"
        aria-describedby="ContactForm-email-error"
      {% endif %}
      placeholder="{{ 'templates.contact.form.email' | t }}"
    >
    <label class="field__label" for="ContactForm-email">{{ 'templates.contact.form.email' | t }} <span aria-hidden="true">*</span></label>
    {%- if form.errors contains 'email' -%}
      <small class="contact__field-error" id="ContactForm-email-error">
        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'accessibility.error' | t }}</span>
        <span class="form__message">{% render 'icon-error' %}{{ form.errors.translated_fields['email'] | capitalize }} {{ form.errors.messages['email'] }}</span>
      </small>
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="tel" id="ContactForm-phone" class="field__input" autocomplete="tel" name="contact[{{ 'templates.contact.form.phone' | t }}]" pattern="[0-9\-]*" value="{% if form.phone %}{{ form.phone }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.phone }}{% endif %}" placeholder="{{ 'templates.contact.form.phone' | t }}">
  <label class="field__label" for="ContactForm-phone">{{ 'templates.contact.form.phone' | t }}</label>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <input class="field__input" autocomplete="subject" type="text" id="ContactForm-subject" name="contact[{{ templates.contact.form.subject | t }}]" value="{% if form.name %}{{ form.subject }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.subject }}{% endif %}" placeholder="Subject">
    <label class="field__label" for="ContactForm-subject">{{ 'templates.contact.form.subject' | t }}</label>
</div>
{%- endform -%}
```

This is en.default.json:-

```
"templates": {
   "contact": {
  "form": {
    "name": "Name",
    "email": "Email",
    "phone": "Phone number",
    "subject": "Subject",
    "comment": "Comment",
    "send": "Send",
    ....
    }
   }
}
```

When I submit the form an email is sent to me. But in the message of the email the subject appears as:

**Contact.Form.Subject**

I want the subject to appear as:

**Subject**

What can I do?

Comment: use this `name="contact[Subject]"` instead of `name="contact[{{ 'contact.form.subject' }}]"`

Comment: It's also not working. Now the subject appears as:- **New customer message on %{creation_date}:**

Comment: Try removing the signle quotes around contact.form.subject so change `name="contact[{{ 'contact.form.subject' }}]"` to `name="contact[{{ contact.form.subject }}]"` both inside <input> and <label>

Comment: Btw question is incomplete post also the <form> so we can see the action="" and any additional js handling the form so we can better understand

Comment: After removing the signle quotes around contact.form.subject both inside <input> and <label> I am getting error on submission `This page isn’t working right now`. This is my website: `https://saarifashion.myshopify.com/`

Comment: Umberto, I have updated my post to make it complete. I could not see any js in the code. Maybe you can see by inspecting.